# Different ways to write $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

[image: Two Examples]

What is a general formula $n(n)$ for this? We know that starting from below, we can see how many numbers a certain $n$ generates by counting the number of numbers contained in the column $n$ is in, along with the numbers in the next column **BUT NOT** the numbers in the same row as $n$, and so on. for example,

$\begin{align}n(1) = 1\\
n(2) = 2\\
n(3) = 3\\
n(4) = 5 = (2 + 2 + 1)\\
n(5) = 7 = (2 + 2 + 2 + 1)\\
n(6) = 11 = (2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 1)\\
n(7) = 15 = (2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 1)\\
n(8) = 21 = (2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 1)\\
n(9) = 27 (2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 6 + 1)\\
n(10) = 35 = (2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 6 + 8 + 1)\\
n(11) = 43 = (2 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 6 + 6 + 8 + 8 + 1)\\
\cdots
\end{align}$

Comment: I think you're looking for the partition function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: dude, don't cheat on PE.

Comment: The best way is probably to use Euler's recursion derived from the pentagonal number theorem.

Comment: The sequence departs from the partition function at $n(8)=21$ -- see http://oeis.org/A000041 -- so either you've started overlooking partitions or you have something else in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't *ever* name a function $n$ and then make its argument $n$ as well (like when you wrote $n(n)$).

That said, it appears you want the *partition function*, which is typically written $p(n)$.  As mentioned in the comments, one of the best ways to compute $p(n)$ is to use Euler's Pentagonal Formula.  One of our users, Paramanand Singh, wrote up a really nice introduction as a [blog entry](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/25/playing-with-partitions-eulers-pentagonal-theorem/) on our community blog.

If you want an approximation, one may consider the [Hardy-Ramanujan asymptotic formula](http://www.theoremoftheday.org/NumberTheory/Partitions/TotDPartitions.pdf), which is given by:
$$p(n) \sim \frac{1}{4n\sqrt 3}\exp\left(2\pi\sqrt{n/6}\right)$$